# Record Name not created when creating visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a custom button on a child . This button allows the user to create a new child object in visualforce from the related list on the parent. However, the child's related list are not showing. I also do not see the record name being generated on the child visual force page and suspect this is why the related list components are not being displayed. Nor can I save the newly instantiated child visualforce page.

The button used URL as content source and passes the parent id for the child's controller;

```
/apex/PROD_Audit_Auto_PolicySample?AccId={!Audit__c.Id}
```

In force.com the Name of the Record name is created according to it's formatting (i.e. SAMPLE-00008) but it is not generated when creating the same child object via the link above to the visualforce page.

Is this causing the child record to not save, hide any related list components ?

**Here is the extension controller on the child;**

```
public with sharing class ParentChildExtensionAUTOsample {

public Audit__c audit;
public Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c child;
String accId;

public ParentChildExtensionAUTOsample(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
{
accID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
this.child = (Auto_Audit_Sample_Policy__c)standardController.getRecord();


audit= [SELECT Id, Policy_Information__c, Policy_Number__c, Prior_Carrier__c, Expiring_Premium__c,         Reinstatement_Information__c, Insured_Location__c, Agent_Information__c, Agent_City__c, Agent_Name__c, 
Driver_Information__c, Age__c, Gender__c, Marital_Status__c, Named_Insured_Add_Driver__c, Occupation__c, Business_Use__c, Vehicle_Information__c, Model_Year__c, Vehicle_Type__c, ISO_Symbol__c, 
Annual_Miles__c, Limit_Information__c, Liability_Limits__c, UM_Limits__c, UIM_Limits__c, UM_UIM_Limits__c, PIP_Limits__c, PIP_Deductible__c, APD_Deductible_Vehicle__c, Premium__c, Rating_Information__c, 
MVR_Violations__c, Policy_Discounts__c, Rating_Tier__c, Credit_Scoring__c, Telematics_UBI__c, Loss_Information__c, CLUE_Report__c, Prior_Carrier_Loss_Experience__c, Company_Loss_Experience__c, Individual_Loss_Detail__c, 
General_Information__c, Signed_Application__c, Vehicle_Photo_Information__c, Proof_of_Ownership__c, Other_Policies__c, UW_Guidelines_Followed__c, Risk_Management_Standards__c, Personal_Auto_Product__c      
FROM Audit__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId') LIMIT 1];


}

public Audit__c getAudit()
{
    return audit;
} 

public PageReference save(){
    // TO DO
    return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: @dashboardReport - did you add to your edit ? I don't see anything in the comparison.

Comment: I added a few tags, and put some formatting onto your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: (1) you need to add your VF page; perhaps a screen shot of the detail page as it initially appears too. (2) Also, you hint that the child object is an auto-number detail record of a master-detail - true? (3) and why is your URL parm called `AccId` when you are fetching an `Audit__c`? Shouldn't it be 'AudId' ?